# How to add sass to webpack + react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, sass, preprocessor

How correctly to add sass(in jsx import 'style.sass') in a config webpack + react?

```
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, './');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/');

var config = {
    entry: APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: BUILD_DIR
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?/,
                include: APP_DIR,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
        ,
        rules: [{
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [{
                loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
            }, {
                loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
            }, {
                loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
            }]
        }]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Error:

> ERROR in ./src/index.jsx Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\steko\Desktop\TEST\m-react\src\index.jsx Unexpected token
>   (9:8) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. |
>   render () { | return ( |  | Hello React Project!!! |

[git](https://github.com/StekolschikovV/webpack-config)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your modules section in webpack do this

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            include: APP_DIR
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: "style-loader",
                use: "css-loader!sass-loader",
            })
        }
    ]
}
```

Then in your plugins area in your webpack code do this

```
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css'),
]
```

You will need this package `extract-text-webpack-plugin`

Please do let me know if you still have any issues.

Answer (score 1):

The `ExtractTextPlugin` above me, is for extracting your js code and css code to 2 separate files. This is great, but not sure that is what you meant.

So this is how I parse sass files in my webpack build.
I can later decide if I leave the css in my js file or extract it.

```
 loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loader: "style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader"
        }
 ]
```

the loaders are applied right to left so:

- parsing the sass file
- then applying the css loader
- and finally the style loader

in the end you will have your css code inside your js output file ready for use, just like any other css file you load.

Answer (score 0):

This might make it more confusing, but I thought to send you a copy of the file that I use for the dev environment which includes SASS and React. you should be able to decifer what is needed and not needed.

I have excluded anything that is directly work related such as IP address used for a proxy in the devServer setup but other than that it is complete.

hope it helps!

```
const webpack           = require('webpack');
const path              = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const Paths = {
    dist:           path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    src:            path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    indexFile:      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.jsx'),
    nodeModulesDir: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
    sassFile:       path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/css/main.scss')
};

const config = {
    devtool: '#source-map',
    entry: {
        main: ['react-hot-loader/patch', 'babel-polyfill', Paths.indexFile, Paths.sassFile],
    },
    output: {
        path: Paths.dist,
        filename: "[name].[hash].bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude:  [Paths.nodeModulesDir],
                use:   [{
                    loader: 'babel-loader?cacheDirectory&cacheIdentifier='+ Math.random(),
                    options: {
                        presets: ["env", "react", "stage-0",
                            ["env", {
                                "targets": {
                                    "browsers": ["last 2 versions", "ie >= 8", "safari >= 7"]
                                },
                                debug: true
                            }]
                        ]
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                modules: true,
                                localIdentName: '[name]_[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
                            }
                        },
                        'postcss-loader'
                    ]
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                modules: false,
                                sourceMap: true,
                                importLoaders: 2,
                                localIdentName: '[name]_[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
                            }
                        },
                        'sass-loader'
                    ]
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpe?g|gif)(\?\S*)?$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader:  'url-loader',
                        options: {
                            limit: 100000,
                            name: '[name].[ext]'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
        modules: ['node_modules', 'src']
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.join(Paths.src, 'index.html')
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({filename: "[name].[contenthash].css", allChunks: true}),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {from: 'assets/images/**/*', to: ''},
            {from: 'assets/fonts/**/*', to: ''},
            {from: 'assets/lang/**/*', to: ''},
            {from: 'assets/js/**/*', to: ''},
            {from: 'src/static/**/*', to: ''}
            ]),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin()
    ],
    devServer: {
        port: 8081,
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        disableHostCheck: true, // so you can use the computers IP address not just 'localhost'/127.0.0.1
        contentBase: Paths.src,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        hot: true,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:8081",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization"
        },
        inline: true
        }
    }
};
```